# Java while loop help to compute the frequency of even numbers from the user

Tags: java, numbers

My Question that I am trying to solve is as follows: "Read in numbers from the user until the user enters -1, and compute the frequency of even numbers from the user".

I have the first part done and it seems to run ok. But I cant get the second part completed where I compute the frequency of even number from the user.

I have copied what I have done so far but i am looking for help to finish it of. I would appreciate anyone's help.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ex2Ass2ParC {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String dataString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer value:/n(the program exits if the input is -1)");
        int data = Integer.parseInt(dataString);
        int count = 0;

        while(data!=-1){
            count++;

            dataString = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer value:/n(the program exits if the input is -1)");
            data=Integer.parseInt(dataString);

        }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The frequency of numbers is"+count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should look into basic `if` statements and the modulo `%` operator

Comment: Do you know how to compute the frequency of even numbers on paper? If I give you the numbers `1, 5, 2, 7`, what is it?

Comment: Well, do you understand what the frequecy of even numbers is. How would you compute it. Let's say I enter 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, what is the frequency and how did you compute it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to compute frequency of numbers of a certain kind you need to count how many such numbers were entered, in addition to the total count of numbers, which you already have.

Add a separate counter, and increment it each time that `data % 2 == 0`, which indicates that the parsed number is even:

```
int count = 0;
int even = 0;
while(data!=-1){
    count++;
    dataString = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer value:/n(the program exits if the input is -1)");
    data=Integer.parseInt(dataString);
    if (data % 2 == 0) {
        even++;
    }
}
```

At the end of the loop divide the count of even numbers by the total count. Make sure that you cast the first count to `double` before performing division, otherwise you would get an integer division resulting in zero or one.

Comment: I sorry. I am only new to the computer programming. I started 3 weeks ago so it is confusing to me when people explain. Where would i be placing the data % 2 == 0?. if I was to enter numbers 2-6 for example numbers 2 and 4 would be even. So do I place this information under while or count? Also I am lost with the double what should be in the program with double?

Comment: @Ciaran 
The  `data % 2 == 0` should be inside an `if` statement -- basically checking if the number is even before increasing the counter. This would be inside the while statement, after receiving the user input.

The double is only if you need the percentage of numbers that are even

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement to check if a number is even instead of just adding to count every time by doing:

```
if (data % 2 == 0) {
    count++;
}
```

So replace `count++` with the statement above.

EDIT

If by frequency you mean percentage, you'll need to create a second local variable that keeps track of the total amount of numbers given

```
double totalNumbers = 0.0;
while(data!=-1){
        totalNumbers++;
        if (data % 2 == 0) {
            count++;
        }

        dataString = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter an integer value:/n(the program exits if the input is -1)");
        data=Integer.parseInt(dataString);

    }
```

And then change the dialog to `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The frequency is: " + (count/totalNumbers));`

Comment: That would give the count, not the frequency.

Comment: I wasn't sure how he wanted frequency, based on the post it seemed like he wanted the amount of times, although I edited my response to be frequency using percentages.